# How to emulate a C-style function pointer with Python functions

Tags: python, function-pointers, primitive

Suppose I have a function that is hard-coded to make a substring lowercase, when instances of that substring are found in a larger string, e.g.:

```
def process_record(header, needle, pattern):
    sequence = needle
    for idx in [m.start() for m in re.finditer(pattern, needle)]:
        offset = idx + len(pattern)
        sequence = sequence[:idx] + needle[idx:offset].lower() + sequence[offset:]
    sys.stdout.write('%s\n%s\n' % (header, sequence))
```

This works fine, e.g.:

```
>>> process_record('>foo', 'ABCDEF', 'BCD')
>foo
AbcdEF
```

What I'd like to do is generalize this, to pass in a string function (`lower`, in this case, but it could be any function of a primitive type or class) as a parameter. Something like:

```
def process_record(header, needle, pattern, fn):
    sequence = needle
    for idx in [m.start() for m in re.finditer(pattern, needle)]:
        offset = idx + len(pattern)
        sequence = sequence[:idx] + needle[idx:offset].fn() + sequence[offset:]
    sys.stdout.write('%s\n%s\n' % (header, sequence))
```

This doesn't work (which is why I'm asking the question), but hopefully this demonstrates the idea, to try to generalize what the function does in a way that is readable.

One option I suppose is to write a helper function that wraps `stringInstance.lower()` and passes copies of strings around, which is inefficient and clumsy. I'm hoping there's a more elegant approach that Python experts know about.

With C, for instance, I'd pass a pointer to the function I want to run as a parameter to `process_record()`, and run the function pointer directly on the variable of interest.

What is the syntax for doing the same when using string primitive functions (or similar on primitive or other classes) in Python?

Comment: `fn(needle[idx:offset])`?

Comment: You can do something like `process_record(..., lambda x: x.lower())` then in the method `fn(strval)`

Answer (score 0):

In general, use this approach:

```
def call_fn(arg, fn):
    return fn(arg)

call_fn('FOO', str.lower) # 'foo'
```

The definition of a method in Python always starts with `self` as it's first argument. By calling the method as an attribute of the *class* you can force the value of that argument.

Comment: As noted in my question, how might I do this without writing a wrapper function that passes parameters by value, and thus makes copies of strings (potentially long ones)?

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a little complex, so I would break this into two different questions:

1) How can you provide functions as arguments?

Functions are objects like everything else, and can be passed around as expected, e.g.:

```
 def apply(val, func):
    # e.g. ("X", string.lower) -> "x"
    #      ("X", lambda x: x * 2) -> "XX"
     return func(val)
```

In your example, you might do

```
def process_record(..., func):
    ...
       sequence = ... func(needle[idx:offset]) ...
    ...
```

An alternative method that I wouldn't recommend would be something like

```
def apply_by_name(val, method_name):
    # e.g. ("X", "lower") -> "x"
    return getattr(val, method_name)()
```

2) How can I apply an effect to each match of a regular expression in a string?

For this I would recommend the built-in 'sub' function, which takes strings as well as functions.

```
>>> re.sub('[aeiou]', '!', 'the quick brown fox')
'th! q!!ck br!wn f!x'

def foo(match):
   v = match.group()
   if v == 'i': return '!!!!!!!'
   elif v in 'eo': return v * 2
   else: return v.upper()

>>> re.sub('[aeiou]', foo, 'the quick brown fox')
'thee qU!!!!!!!ck broown foox'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. As noted in my question, how might I do this without writing a wrapper function that passes parameters by value, and thus makes copies of strings (potentially long ones)?

Comment: @AlexReynolds I don't know the specifics you are dealing with, but I am worried this is an http://xyproblem.info/ .  The overhead of doing regular expression matching likely dwarfs any 'copy of a string' issues.  In the case of re.sub, I believe the implementation will reconstruct the string as it goes, and handle it one at a time so you will be left with at most 2x your original string in memory (in the case and at the moment that the regex matches the entire string).